# Spring cloud Gateway

Tags: spring, cloud, gateway

I have anexo API with some endpoints, like:

```
 Localhsost:8080/api/clients  -> GET findall
 Localhsost:8080/api/clients/id -> GET findByID
 Localhsost:8080/api/clients -> POST insert a cliente
 Localhsost:8080/api/clients/id DELETE deleteByID
```

How do I use Spring Cloud Gateway with those endpoints?

Comment: You don't really need to worry about which endpoints you have so much as which applications and what paths you want to put them on. If you only have one application you might not need a gateway at all. Are there particular features of Spring cloud gateway that you want to use?

Comment: I actually have several endpoints, like:
8080 / clients
8081 / users
8082 / product
8083 / sales

and each endpoint there are httpd verbs, to delete, insert, search ...

I saw some tutorials but I did not understand how to configure the gateway correctly for my endpoints.

Comment: Maybe you could start by following https://dzone.com/articles/spring-cloud-gateway-configuring-a-simple-route with a property-based route in the application.yaml and configuring just one of your services to begin with? So replacing http://httpbin.org with http://localhost:8080 and replacing `props` with `client`. You could test that by making an http get call and then try adding in a second service (e.g. users) afterwards.

Comment: Is there any difference between using RouteLocatorBuilder or .yml?
And if I want to use .properties and not .yml, how do I configure it? I do not see tutorial to configure the .properties.
And thank you for the help.

Comment: It's different ways of doing the same thing. I think application.properties is possible but yaml is much easier because the config contains collections. People seem to have had problems trying to use properties (e.g. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/384)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having trouble seeing where to start you could try following property-based the example from the dzone article ['Spring Cloud Gateway - Configuring a Simple Route'](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-cloud-gateway-configuring-a-simple-route). You could configure just one of your services to begin with. That example suggests creating a spring cloud gateway project from the [spring initializr](http://start.spring.io/) by selecting the 'gateway' dependency and adding a route to the application.yaml:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes: 
        - predicates:
            - Path=/props/**
          filters:
            - StripPrefix=1
          uri: "http://httpbin.org"
```

So you could replace `httpbin.org` with `localhost:8080` and replace `/props/**` with your path - `/api/clients/**`. You could test that by making an http get call and then try adding in a second service afterwards. In your case I suspect you want to remove the filter to strip the prefix as it sounds like your service is exposing an `/api/clients` endpoint so you'd presumably want to preserve that whole path. That's something [you'd need to check](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-gateway.adoc#stripprefix-gatewayfilter-factory).

Comment: Thx for save my day sir.